# How to make a folder (D:\xyz) accessible to only me in Windows-XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I'm using Windows XP on my lab computer. There is a global folder (d:\xyz). This is my folder and I want this folder to be accessible to only me. It should be invisible even if it is visible they shouldn't be able to open this folder.

For now my account has administrative privilages. After few days, I don't know if the Admin lets me have these privilages or not.

I heard that soon our XP machines will be upgraded to either vista or windows 7. Will the method of making folder in accessible change for other Windows OSes?

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Remember that an administrator can always grant themselves the privileges to access that folder, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each file and folder has an Access Control List (ACL) that determines who can access it.
You can view and change the permissions with the `cacls.exe` command.
(Link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true), or you can type `cacls /?` for details.)

You can mark a folder as 'hidden' with the command `attrib +h d:\xyz`.
(Link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true), or you can type `attrib /?` for details.)

Note these are only really any good for giving you privacy from other users, not from other administrators —if you were thinking of (for example) secretly installing a game on a works computer, then playing tricks with folder permissions may make it **more** likely to bring it to a sysadmins attention since many administrators run scripts to check for folders with odd file permissions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder, and select "Security". There are the access rules for the file. Click on "Everyone", and deselect all privileges. There are other rules, usually something like "Administrators", "Owner" and . Just be sure nothing is allowed for anyone else than you.

This should work the same on other Windows versions as well. This is how an NTFS filesystem works, which I don't think that changed between Win XP and 7.